# Puppet Syntax: How to make a collection that only applies to resources in a given class?

Tags: syntax, puppet

In Puppet, say I have a `class` which contains numerous `file` and `package` resources. I want to use resource chaining ( `->` and `~>` ) to ensure that they get managed in the proper order. I want all `file` resources to be managed before `package` resources. I read the [Puppet Language Guide section on resource chaining](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/language_guide.html#chaining-resources), and tried its suggestion, using collections, like so:

`File <| |> -> Package["package1"] -> Package["package2"]` and so on.

However, that didn't work, and some really weird behavior occurred: that instruction managed *every single `file` object* in my Puppet configuration, not just in the `class` I was working on, before the `package`s specified.

How would I use collections to say "manage every `file` object *in this class only* before the specified resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not what you're looking for but you could separate your File resources into a separate manifest mymodule::myfiles and then in do Class['Mymodule::Myfiles'] -> Package['package1'] and so on.

Comment: Good idea! If nobody comes up with the "right way" in a couple of days, I'll go with that. I could just include the subclass in the main class, and, from the outside at least, everything would be rosy.